# How can I insert an if statement into this series of promises? (Vue JS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

(Vue JS) I'm having difficulties inserting an if statement within these promises. I'd like to us an 'if (res.status===200)' right after receiving the response. How can I break this up a little? I'm getting errors every time I try.

```
fetchFeatured() {
console.log("fetching featured video");
  fetch(
    `${this.url}?part=${this.part}&maxResults=${
      this.maxResults
    }&playlistId=${this.playlistId}&key=${this.key}`
  )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json.items);
      this.videos = json.items;
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the `if` check into the first `.then`. If the status is not 200, you can throw an error to break out of the `.then` chain early (though calling `.json()` on the bad response would also throw an error):

```
fetchFeatured() {
  console.log("fetching featured video");
  const url = `${this.url}?part=${this.part}&maxResults=${
    this.maxResults
    }&playlistId=${this.playlistId}&key=${this.key}`;
  return fetch(url)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status===200) {
        return res.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error('Status was not 200!');
      }
    })
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json.items);
      this.videos = json.items;
  });
}
```

Make sure to `return` the `fetch` Promise chain. Then, calls of `fetchFeatured` can handle errors by putting a `.catch` onto the end, for example

```
this.fetchFeatured()
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Bad response:', err);
    // populate error element with error message
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're insisting on controlling the flow with `if`, as opposed to with the Promise API, then you can conditionally return another promise chain from inside `then`. The following will return and not do anything if `res.status` is anything other than 200:

```
fetchFeatured() {
  console.log('fetching featured video');

  fetch('URL WITH PARAMS HERE')
    .then(res => {
      // Here's the `if` you're looking for:
      if (res.status !== 200) return;

      // Return a promise chain from inside our promise chain!
      return res.json().then(json => {
        console.log(json.items);
        this.videos = json.items;
      });
    });
}
```

The previous paradigm leads to indentation hell - in general you'll be much happier working with `async` + `await`:

```
async fetchFeatured() {
  let res = await fetch('URL WITH PARAMS HERE');
  if (res.status !== 200) return;
  let json = await res.json();
  console.log(json.items);
  this.videos = json.items;
}
```